# Vim stops treating "<Plug>" as a keyword to call functions in insert mode

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, key-bindings, plugin-vim-latex

I have the following configuration in my vimrc file.

```
inoremap <C-A> <Plug>InsertComment
```

And somewhere in my vim folder I defined

```
inoremap <silent> <Plug>InsertComment <ESC>:call INSERT_MY_COMMENT
```

The mapping worked really well after I configured it. But somehow recently it stopped functioning. And whenever I can to use the Key-bind in the insert mode, instead calling the function that I mapped, vim will just paste the entire `<Plug>InsertComment` thing to my buffer.

I tried to debug and found out that if I map

`inoremap <C-A> <ESC>:call INSERT_MY_COMMENT`

it still works as desired, which means there must be something wrong with the `<Plug>` part.

But I really have no clue on why `<Plug>` would stop being interpreted by vim as a handle to call other plugins.

I also tried to manually copy and paste

```
inoremap <silent> <Plug>InsertComment <ESC>:call INSERT_MY_COMMENT
inoremap <C-A> <Plug>InsertComment
```

in to vim's command line, just to make sure the configurations have not accidentally been unset. But still, vim wouldn't accept that as a function, but rather copy the plain text to buffer.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a nore mapping to tie a sequence of keys to `<plug>something`, even if there is a mapping behind that `<plug>something`, it'll be ignored. In the documentation, `nore` is said to prevent *recursion*. That's what is happening here.

That means that: the `<plug>something` mapping shall indeed be defined with `noremap`, but the actual keybinding chosen shall not.

IOW, the correct definitions become

```
" in a plugin: 
inoremap <silent> <Plug>InsertComment <c-o>:call INSERT_MY_COMMENT()<cr>

" in your .vimrc
imap <C-A> <Plug>InsertComment
```

Comment: Ah, slightly faster :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using

```
inoremap <C-A> <Plug>InsertComment
```

That basically means, that recursive resolution of your mapped keys is **prevented** which is usually not what you want. Therefore change your mapping to

```
imap <C-A> <Plug>InsertComment
```

See also the extensive [help](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#using-%3CPlug%3E)

(Start reading from the paragraph that starts with **MAPPING**)